# Where do I find the selenium-server Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, selenium

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I want to use the Selenium Maven plugin's selenese goal to run some Selenium tests, but I can't find the necessary selenium-server JAR.  I have this in my pom.xml ...

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.openqa.selenium.server</groupId> 
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId> 
        <version>0.9.2</version> 
    </dependency>
```

but when I run my build I get the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cme-productplus-web2: Could not resolve dependencies for project cme-productplus2:cme-productplus-web2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.openqa.selenium.server:selenium-server:jar:0.9.2in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Where do I get this mysterious JAR file or what repository do I need to add to find it?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: 0.9.2?! [Current is 2.17](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server/2.17.0). Also, see the [maven-selenium dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/selenium-maven-plugin/2.2).

Comment: Nope, it's [2.18.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server/2.18.0/) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available from any Maven repo.

you have to download it (http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/), and add it manually in your local repository (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html).

Comment: But a [current version is](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-rc/1.0.2).

Comment: Not the current one, but a "younger" one ;-)  The latest is available [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server/2.18.0/).

Comment: ... Either way, a far cry from 0.9.2, and not selenium-rc, but the dependency the OP asked about.